# Spock unit tests with ant build

Tags: ant, junit, spock

I'm writing a unit test with Spock. I want to check all elements of an array using the spock

```
when: then:
```

block. I found the syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138769/asserting-on-a-list-of-items-in-spock) from the accepted answer. and based on that I wrote something like this -

```
then:    
myArray.every { (it >= 0) && (it < 10) }
```

This works correctly with IntelliJ but when I build the test using Ant, it fails.

Ant and groovy setup - taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315411/spock-without-maven-or-gradle). I could see it working for simple conditions like myArray.length == 8.

Groovy version - 2.4.5

Spock version - spock-core-1.0-groovy-2.4.jar

JDK 1.8

Ant 1.9.6

Error -

```
[junit] Testcase: initializationError took 0 sec
[junit]     Caused an ERROR
[junit] Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
[junit] java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
[junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
[junit]
[junit] Testcase: initializationError took 0 sec
[junit]     Caused an ERROR
[junit] No runnable methods
[junit] java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
[junit]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
[junit]
[junit] Test package.MyTest$__spock_feature_0_0_closure1 FAILED
```

On looking at the class file created by the ant build, I see

```
public void $spock_feature_0_0(Object obj){
...
...
class __spock_feature_0_0_closure1 extends Closure implements GeneratedClosure {
}
...
...
new __spock_feature_0_0_closure1()
}
```

So looks like the closure is not accessible using Reflection!! Any thoughts? 
Is my ant groovy configuration messed up(as I said earlier, simpler tests are working for me, so i hope not!)?, or am i just expecting too much from Spock.

*An example of the scenario* -

```
public class SpockTest extends Specification{

public def "example"(){
    given:
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    when:
    arr[0] = 1;

    then:
    arr.every { (it >= 0) }
}
}
```

*Below junit also fails to run with the same error*-

```
public class TestClass {
 public int test1() {
   class testInner {//local class
     int a = 100;
     public int getA() {
       return a;
     }
   }
 return new testInner().getA();
 }
 @Test
 public void test2() {
   System.out.println(test1());
   assert 100 == test1();
 }
}
```

UPDATE(29-Feb-16) - With the discussions so far, it seems like the problem is with Ant. Only the junit and groovy/Spock tests using/compiling to local classes are giving errors. Simpler cases are working fine.

Comment: Can you post your whole Spock test? Does it extend Specification?

Comment: hi kazanaki, I have added an example for your reference.

Comment: Your test works fine in the Spock web console. https://meetspock.appspot.com. So I think your setup is wrong (given that it also works in Intellij)

Comment: Thanks for checking. I understand that there is something wrong with the setup. The ".every" statement compiles into a local class in byte code. I looked at it and wrote a junit test which also fails, to my surprise!! So I think i can narrow it down to Ant. But not sure what exactly.(Updated main comments with junit test, ant environment information). Thoughts?